# Booted from NFS Linux has no permission for su command

Tags: linux, permissions, boot, su, u-boot

I've booted Linux from `NFS` with Android system. And now I have to execute command as super use in `minicom`. But system doesn't allow me to switch to super user mode. Every time when I type:

```
shell@blaze_tablet:/ $ su
```

I see:

```
su: permission denied
```

There is parameter at `bootargs` I've added in u-boot  `androidboot.selinux=disabled` wich I thought would help. But it doesn't.
Can problem be with permission to some files on `NFS`? Or I missed any parameter in `bootargs`?

**Update**

The content of my `/etc/exports` file

```
# /etc/exports: the access control list for filesystems which may be exported
#       to NFS clients.  See exports(5).
#
# Example for NFSv2 and NFSv3:
# /srv/homes       hostname1(rw,sync,no_subtree_check) hostname2(ro,sync,no_subtree_check)
#
# Example for NFSv4:
# /srv/nfs4        gss/krb5i(rw,sync,fsid=0,crossmnt,no_subtree_check)
# /srv/nfs4/homes  gss/krb5i(rw,sync,no_subtree_check)
/export/rfs    *(rw,nohide,insecure,no_subtree_check,async,no_root_squash)
```

Comment: this may help http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/61876/su-permission-denied-despite-correct-password

Comment: @IjazKhan, thank you for help. But system on my device doesn't have folder named `pam.d`, I can find it only on my host laptop Ubuntu system. Instructions from the best answer don't help too. System doesn't know command `groups`. When I type command `su` system doesn't request password. I can't find `bin/su` but I  have `xbin/su` with required permissions. If I will boot system on device without `NFS` using internal `system` and `rootfs` partitions command `su` executes normally. In kernel `menuconfig` I didn't find `grsecurity`. I haven't looked in error logs yet, but I will do it now.

Comment: Can you provide the result of `ls -l` for the `su` executable (`ls -l $(type -p su)`, or whatever works for your shell) please

Comment: You did run `exportfs -var` on the NFS server after updating `/etc/exports`? (Or restart the server.)

Comment: @roaima, result of execution of `ls -l $(type -p su)`:`-rwxr-xr-x root     root       157400 2016-04-21 19:11 su`

Comment: you are missing the `+s` bit on the file, run `chmod u+s /path/to/su` to fix it

Comment: @roaima, sorry, didn't see your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote:

> result of execution of `ls -l $(type -p su)`
>
> ```
> -rwxr-xr-x root root 157400 2016-04-21 19:11 su
> ```

There's your problem. `su` is missing the setuid root bit. The permissions should look like this:

```
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 40040 Nov 12  2015 /bin/su
```

There are three possibilities for this situation.

1. The `su` executable on the server is not setuid (check with `ls -l $(type -p su)` on the server)
2. The NFS mount on the client does not include - or explicitly excludes - the setuid bit. Ensure you don't have `nosuid` on your `mount` command, and if in doubt add `suid` as an explicit option
3. Android security is implemented completely differently to Unix/Linux security. If this is the case I can't help you further

Answer (score 1):

Typically this happens if the NFS share isn't exported properly.

By default, the `root` user is mapped to `nobody`.  This means that when you try and run `su` (which is suid root) then you will try to access files on the NFS server as user `nobody`... and this won't let you read `/etc/shadow` and similar.

You didn't say what your NFS server is, but if it's the normal Linux one then you need to add `no_root_squash` to the export.

e.g.

```
/directory client(rw,no_root_squash,async,insecure)
```

Now the `root` user will access the files as if it was uid 0, and so can read the protected files.

Comment: thank you for answer. But my file ` /etc/exports` already contains all required parameters that your wrote. I found one useless parameter, but it has no effect.

Comment: @roaima, I've updated my question with content of my `/etc/exports` file. Useless parameter is `nohide`